# Como montar uma piramide de numero 1 de 20 linhas consecutivas?

Tags: javascript, for

Tenho o código:

```js
let i = 0

for(i = 0; i<= 20; i++){
    const p  = 1**i
    console.log(p)
}
```

E espero uma saída como:

```
1
11
111
1111
11111
111111
1111111
11111111
```

Mas não estou conseguindo criar essa forma de "pirâmide".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uma opção que considero um pouco mais adequada para esse tipo de coisa é utilizar o método [`String.prototype.repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat), que repete uma *string* N vezes.

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  console.log('1'.repeat(i));
}
```

<sup>Note que esse método foi introduzido na especificação ECMAScript 2015 (ES6). Embora o suporte seja, atualmente, bem alto — 94,5% no momento em que escrevo isto —, vale consultar uma [tabela de compatibilidade](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_string_repeat) antes de utilizá-lo. Você pode utilizar um [*polyfill*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat#Polyfill) para contornar eventual falta de suporte. O mesmo cuidado de uso deve ser tomado com as declarações `let` e `const`.</sup>

Comment: Boa. Vi essa opção, mas preferi pelo "old javascript". +1

Comment: **Nota** : Essa função abençoada não funciona no Internet Explorer.

Comment: Obrigado pela observação, @WallaceMaxters! :-)

Comment: Boa observação sobre o `let`. Como eu to usando a versão "old", mudei a minha resposta pra `var`.

Comment: não conhecia essa opção de repeat, obrigado por me esclarecer

Answer (score 2):

Por acaso, você deseja isso?

```js
for (var i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {

    var p = Array(i + 1).join('1');

    console.log(p);
}
```

A função `Array`, quando adicionado um número, gerará um array com itens vazios, de acordo com essa quantidade passada.

Exemplo:

```js
console.log(Array(5))

console.log(Array(2))

console.log(Array(10))
```

A função `join` por sua vez, unirá todo esse array usando o número `'1'` como "cola".

Veja:

```js
console.log(Array(4).join('1'))

console.log(Array(7).join('5'))

console.log(Array(10).join('$'))
```

Comment: resolveu meu problema muito grato pela atenção.